# Check user email address before Place Order button is pressed in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a special product on our WooCommerce shop and we want it to be purchased only once per email address. **Please note that Customer is NOT logged in**. Is there a way to check the email address user enters on the checkout page before the order is placed and show a message that they have already purchased the product with this email address and disable the Place Order button. If customer changes the email address, they can proceed with the purchase as long as the email address has never been used previously to purchase that product.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this link here. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/prevent-repeat-purchase-with-woocommerce/

It suggests using the wc_customer_bought_product function to check against the user's email address to see if they have previously purchased the product.

```
 // return false if the customer has bought the product
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }
```

It requires a user to be logged in but there is no reason you couldn't use ajax at the checkout and test the email form field (in place of **wp_get_current_user()->user_email**) with that function and then if you get a true response you could replace the submit button from the checkout form with an error message.